# I'm trying to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Viewcomponent but the namespace isn't recognized

Tags: asp.net-core

So I am going through an aspnetcore book and I want to create view components for this app I inherited but I'm struggling to include the correct framework.

The app I'm working on has a packages.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AjaxControlToolkit" version="7.0123" targetFramework="net45" />   
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.6" targetFramework="net47" />
  ...

</packages>
```

What do I need to add to use Viewcomponent from aspnetcore ?

Comment: You are using .Net Framework 4.7, but not ASP.NET Core

Comment: Can you use both? Can I target both?  how would I target aspnetcore? Is it a bad idea to use aspnet core?

Comment: This is a great place to start: [Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/) package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc -Version 2.2.0
```

then add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;` to use `ViewComponent`